# JavaScript: Write to current HTML document using input from a separate HTML document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

**Preface:** Hi, all! Here goes. First and foremost, I am not familiar with jquery, so any jquery code posted will be irrelevant to me until i research it. I'm newly teaching myself JS. I have decent XHTML experience, decent CSS3 familiarity/understanding, and some (very little) application programming experience (C++, Java).

**The Situation:** I'm designing a website's home page whereon, with JavaScript *enabled*, links are *overwritten* and *instead of loading a new HTML document/page* for each main link, I *alter sections*  of the home page using JS.

**The challenge:** I want to load new page content without loading an entirely separate page. A similar *old HTML solution* to such a challenge was to load page *frames,* right? I want to overwrite an entire container element using content from another separate HTML file on the server. (The external file could be tailored to fit into the main page, but it would be *even better* if I could pull a SECTION of an external HTML document, perhaps one element).

- Can I do this using only JavaScript?
- If not, what other scripting could be used *in conjunction* with JS?
- Would I need to implement "AJAX"?
- Must I use "HTML DOM"? - Edit: I see that DOM is just integral to the function of HTML etc.

Thank you all for your patience and your expert advice. I <3 StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that using Javascript and jQuery, take a look at the load() method that's exactly what you need

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Yes it is using AJAX, but it's really easy to use don't worry.

Comment: This was the simplest solution as it only required including the latest jQuery JavaScript library! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do this using only JavaScript?

No, because the server will need to serve you the content / data that you wish to place in the HTML page. You'll need to combine client-side scripting (JavaScript) with functionality on the web server (see your next question below).

> If not, what other scripting could be used in conjunction with JS?

That would be your server-side language, such as PHP, Ruby, or Python.

> Would I need to implement "AJAX"?

Yes, what you described is implemented using Ajax. You've mentioned the jQuery library and it indeed has functionality to perform an Ajax call to the server (see [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). The basic idea is: your JavaScript code performs an Ajax call, your web server returns the HTML and then your JavaScript code receives it and places it in the HTML page.

> Must I use "HTML DOM"?

Web pages always make use of "HTML DOM". You could read the article about [Document Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) on Wikipedia for more information: you have to use DOM but not by choice - it's part of how web pages work.

Comment: So, the other answer does not state or imply that any server-side scripting is required on my part, right? Can I do it by simply scripting some jquery?

Comment: As long as the html content you are loading is static content and doesn't rely on any dynamic values from the server (for example - data specific to a logged in user), you can get away with just making the .load() ajax request via jquery.